# implement prototype cell when I click a button in another view Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, viewcontroller

My program has one view controller and a tableView controller.
I intend to upgrade my tableview cell with the current time everyTime I click a button in viewController.

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()
  @property(nonatomic,strong) Brain* brain;
  @property(nonatomic,readonly)TimeTableController* tableControl;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _brain=[[Brain alloc] init];
  _tableControl=[[TimeTableController alloc] init];
}
- (IBAction)actionTime:(id)sender {
   [self.tableControl.entryTime addObject:[self.brain currentTime]];
}
```

timeTableController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *timeTable;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* entryTime;
```

timeTableController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _entryTime=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  _timeTable=[[UITableView alloc] init];


  #pragma mark - Table view data source

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {   if(!_entryTime) return 0;
  else
      return 1;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return [_entryTime count];
  }
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 { ...
  self.cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.entryTime objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
  }
[self.tableControl.timeTable reloadData];
 return cell;
}
```

However, when I press the button, nothing happens. Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: ops, just a correction: [self.tableControl.timeTable reloadData] is in - (IBAction)actionTime:(id)sender

Comment: did you copy/paste this code, or did you retype it? Your numberOfSectionsInTableView seem to be missing a couple of curly braces around the if and else conditionals.

Comment: I retype it, but it's all right in numberOsSectionsInTableView
One of problems is that in - (IBAction)actionTime:(id)sender an object is not being added to _timeControl.entryTime when I press button

Comment: How do you get TimeTableController on screen? I think your problem is that you're alloc init'ing an instance of TimeTableController in ViewController, but that's not the same instance that you put on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* timeLabel;
```

?

Then dont forget to connect that in your xib file after placing a label in your custom cell that is located in the xib file.